# Stretching a video?

Tags: html, video, html5-video, stretching

I am trying to stretch the video that I have. It has to be 400 X 400 stretched. I tried using the "stretchtofit" value="true" but that doesn't work and I need the video centered under the heading. I'm curious as to what I use to stretch the video?  This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html
   PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
<title>Lab 8-3</title>

</head>
<body>

<div style="text-align: center">
    <img style="border: 0" src="magiclogo.png" width="325" height="88" alt="Logo" />
</div>

<div style="position: absolute; top: 110px; left: 310px">


    <object data="magicshow.wmv" height="400" width="400">
        <param name="showcontrols" value="false" />
        <param name="stretchtofit" value="true" />

    </object>

</div>

<object classid="clsid:6BF52A52-394A-11D3-B153-00C04F79FAA6">

        <param name="URL" value="magicmusic.mp3" />
          <param name="uimode" value="invisible" />

    </object>   

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

why aren't you using `<video>` tag. you can set the size easily.

```
<video width="400" height="400" controls>
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```